# PHP / Laravel - Unit Test for Directory Permissions

Tags: php, linux, laravel, permissions, phpunit

I have a Laravel application which has various folders that contain user uploads.  Additionally, there are also seeded upload data that serves as dummy data.

When the app is pulled to the Staging server, the permissions sometimes fails on the uploads directories.  So I wanted to write some tests to check that the directories/files are in fact writable

I've tired things like this:

```
$this->assertEquals(substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms(sprintf("%s/%s", public_path(), $document->base_dir))), -4), '0775');
```

However, even if the test passes, the uploads still fails due to permissions when trying it in the browser.

I also tried:

```
$this->assertTrue(is_writable(sprintf("%s/%s", public_path(), $document->base_dir)));
```

But this seemed just as inaccurate.  the test would pass, but the uploads were still failing.

My question: I assume this has to do with the Users that are invoked when running the tests vs execution in the browser.  So is there a more accurate way to go about testing this via PHP?

Comment: just use plain php `<?php if(!is_writable($file_or_dir)){ chmod($file_or_dir,0777); } ?>`

Comment: yeah, thats exactly what i tried above: `is_writable()` however even when that code returned true, there were instances where the actual file upload process would still error because of insufficient permissions

Comment: yes I agree but my code checks if not writable then makes writable  and you can perform what your file manipulation outside the condition knowing its been checked and changed as necessary

Comment: but thats the problem.  The code `is_writable()` returns true.  However, when I then go and test an upload in the browser, it fails because of permissions issues on that directory.  So writing an `if()` statement won't help because it seems to inaccurately be returning true

Comment: I would add that checking by default to my app anyway - mainly because I am lazy. Have you printed out `sprintf("%s/%s", public_path(), $document->base_dir)` and are sure its the dir you think it is?

Comment: This sort of thing is maybe best tested with behavioral testing, such as via phpunit's selenium integration https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/selenium.html  In a unit test, you can verify the unix perms are set, but as you discovered, you can't prove it works in the browser.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yeah perhaps you're right about that,  I'll give that a try.

Comment: does the web user has the permissions for those directories ?